# Unable to unset or clear joomla virtuemart cart session variable

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I create a button and i want to reset cart on click event. The session variable which holds the cart value is

```
print_r(unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']));
```

I tried

```
$session->clear('__vm','vmcart');
```

But it does't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, for the VM 2 should come another solution!
In file /components/com_virtuemart/cart/default_pricelist.php add link:

```
<a href="<?=JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&task=deleteCart' ) ?>">Clear cart</a>
```

In components/com_virtuemart/controllers/cart.php add function:

```
public function deleteCart() {
   $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
   $cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();
   if ($cart->removeCart()) {
      $mainframe->enqueueMessage('All is done.');
   } else {
      $mainframe->enqueueMessage('Error with deleting.', 'error');
   }
   $mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart'));
}
```

And in components/com_virtuemart/helpers/cart.php

```
public function removeCart() {
   if (!empty($this->products)) {
      foreach ( $this->products as $key => $val ) {
         unset($this->products[$key]);
         $this->setCartIntoSession();
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

Please try it! And let me know if something did not work - certainly help!

Comment: could you please indicate the file path ? i could't find any file with such name